# Python Change Output Folder of Java Executable

Tags: java, python, subprocess, minecraft

So I'm working on a basic multipurpose script which allows you to run minecraft server .jar files in python. Here is my current code:

```
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

for output_line in run_command('java -jar jar\\minecraft.jar'):
    print(output_line)
```

Also here is my current file layout:

```
/exec.py
/jar/jarfile.jar
```

So you can see it runs the jar file but the thing is when the jar file is run it creates all these files and folders for all the server stuff, but all the files get created in the main directory as the script running it but I want them to be created in the jar folder or another folder of my choice, so how would I get this? I've looked all over and can't find anything to match my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cwd` parameter that works for any executable:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

def run_command(command, **kwargs):
    with subprocess.Popen(command,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                          bufsize=1,
                          **kwargs) as p:
        yield from p.stdout
    # close p.stdout, call p.wait() automatically

for line in run_command(r'java -jar c:\jar\minecraft.jar',
                        cwd=r'D:\working directory',
                        universal_newlines=True):
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/ServerTest/Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    universal_newlines=True):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/ServerTest/Test.py", line 8, in run_command
    **kwargs) as p:
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Comment: @DanielAlexander: Do you understand what *"The directory name is invalid"*  means? Have you forgot `r''` to make raw-string literal? Note: `'\n'` and `r'\n'` are different things in Python.

Comment: I figured out was wrong, I was trying to run the jar file from a subdirectory in the root folder like /jar/minecraft.jar but because we changed the CWD it thinks the server is in D:\working directory\jar\minecraft.jar so are there anyways around it?

Comment: @DanielAlexander: pass the full path to `minecraft.jar` (with the drive letter).

Answer (score -1):

Specify **user.dir** property ([default working directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)):

```
run_command('java -Duser.dir=/your_path_here -jar jar\\minecraft.jar'):
```

Comment: Tried this, it just gives you this error:

    Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer

So what now?